# Prepared Statement always returns 0 on if

Tags: php, mysqli

I´m trying to get the count from a SQL:

```
function sqlCheckUserExists() 
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();   
    $stmt->store_result();  
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    if($count === 1 OR $count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        elseif($count === 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

And calling it with:

```
if (sqlCheckUserExists) {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>202));
}
```

The query is fine like it is. I just want to know if mail is already in the table or not.

As reponse I´m always getting "statusCode: 201" = "0" or "false".

Comment: `if($count === 1 OR $count > 0)` is the same as just `if($count > 0)`

Comment: FYI, you never execute `$stmt->close()`, since you return in both the `if` and `else if`. You should do that before the `if`.

Comment: You're never calling the function: `if (sqlCheckUserExists)` should be `if (sqlCheckUserExists())`

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$email`? Maybe it should be a function parameter?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$conn`? That should also be a function parameter, or use `global $conn;`

Comment: `elseif($count === 0)` should just be `else`.

Comment: And when you have `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you can simplify it to just `return condition;`

Comment: Turn your `error_reporting` on and up so that you see all the warning/error messages your code is generating, which would point you in the correct direction much more quickly.

Comment: $conn comes from a dbconf.php  ```<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
?>```

Answer (score 1):

You missed fetch()

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

And $conn also

```
function sqlCheckUserExists($conn) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();   
    $stmt->store_result();  
    $stmt->bind_result($count);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();  // close it before return
    return $count > 0; // returns true if count is more than zero else false
 
}

if (sqlCheckUserExists($conn)) {

}
```

Comment: Changed nothing:  Response is allways/again statusCode: 202.

Comment: Are you not getting any errors ? Have you checked your mysql query ? Did you run it in phpmyadmin ? && Count != 0 ???